# Get the value of the accessed field within a get pointcut

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut

I have a pointcut which listens to access to an field in DBRow and all subclasses

```
before(DBRow targ) throws DBException: get(@InDB * DBRow+.*) && target(targ) {
    targ.load();
}
```

I now need to determine the value of the accesed field, that is specified by the get pointcut.
Is this possible in AspectJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `set()` pointcuts you can bind the value via `args()`, but not for `get()` pointcuts. So in order to get the value without any hacky reflection tricks, just use an `around()` advice instead of `before()`. This way you can get the field value as a return value of `proceed()`:

```java
Object around(DBRow dbRow) : get(@InDB * DBRow+.*) && target(dbRow) {
    Object value = proceed(dbRow);
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("  " + dbRow + " -> " + value);
    dbRow.load();
    return value;
}
```